# Cannot set header in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am unable to redirect to home when user log in successfully. Being a beginner i am stuck.
This is the route that is authenticating . The below one is another route called home. I want to show homepage.html when user logges in successfully

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var number = request.body.number;
    var password = request.body.pwd;

     if (number && password) {
    var sql = `SELECT 
            fyp_helpers.Mobile_number AS number,
            fyp_helpers.Password AS  Password
        FROM fyp_helpers 
        WHERE Mobile_number = ? 
    UNION 
        SELECT 
            fyp_employers.Employer_Contact AS number ,
            fyp_employers.Employer_Password AS Employer_Password
        FROM fyp_employers 
        WHERE Employer_Contact = ?`;
    connection.query(sql, [number, number], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            var hashedPassword = results[0].Password;
            bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword, function (cryptErr, cryptResult) {
                if (cryptResult) {
                    request.session.loggedin = true;
                    request.session.number = number;
                    response.redirect('/home');
                } else {
                    response.send('Incorrect Password!');
                    console.log(cryptErr);
                }
                response.end();
            });
        } else {
            response.send('User not registered');
        }
    });
}
        else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }

});
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
         response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/HomePage.html'));
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});
app.listen(3000);
```

This is the error i am getting and i am not redirecting to homepage. KIndly help

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something before that if-statement. Please provide the full handler.

Comment: @jishi i have updated code

Comment: Try calling ``console.log(res.headersSent);`` every now and then, to find out where the problem lies.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes it is showing ``` false``` in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` and `sendFile` will both send a response and complete the request, calling `end` will also try send a response (hence the error).

Remove all the calls to `response.end`, you don't need them.

Comment: i did not get it?

Comment: Did not get what?

Comment: Thank you so much.Now i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set headers on a request.  You want to set it on the response.

Comment: How to do that?